# Increasing networkx tolerance when attempting to find end nodes

Tags: python, parameters, networkx

I have a waterline dataset (.shp) where I have been using Shortest Path (Point to Point) analysis in QGIS 3.16. Using QGIS, I have found that if I do not increase the Topology tolerance parameter in the Shortest Path window I get the error: "There is no route from start point to end point.". However, if I adjust the Topology tolerance up by 1' I can get the correct path.

When I perform the same analysis in NetworkX I think I am encountering a similar issue. Where I will get an error like:

> NetworkXNoPath: No path between (-121.16730791899134,
> 44.292191414768645) and (-121.17873042113929, 44.263451141699434)

even though I have performed this analysis successfully in QGIS.

Does NetworkX have a parameter that can increase the detectable edge of a node?

Example of successful Shortest Path in QGIS that NetworkX is unable to id correctly:

[image]

Comment: In QGIS: "Snap geometries to layer". Snap it to itself

Comment: I was hoping to get some insight into NetworkX, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and used `snap geometries to layer` set the input and reference to itself. You have to use the cleanest line you'll ever used in terms of topology.